# Rails link_to unless something then link elsewhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this at the moment

```
<%= link_to 'Compare', event_path(event.id), class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

simple link to, Nothing fancy.

However, What im wanting to do, Is when users click the button to compare, If the event.id has a value inside column_a it will redirect to the `/eventinfo/(data value inside column_a).html.erb`

How do i go about this?

This is currently ona  results page populated from searchkick if that helps at all?

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to` only builds a link; you'll need to implement this logic yourself. The `event.id` is a number, so it can't have a value in `column_a` - I assume you meant `column_a` exists on `event`.

```
<%- if event.column_a.present? -%>
  <%= link_to 'Compare', eventinfo_path(event.column_a) %>
<%- else -%>
  <%= link_to 'Compare', event_path(event.id) %>
<%- end -%>
```

For a clean template or reuse, you could put this logic into a helper method that either generates the whole link or selects the desired URL.

Comment: I actually did this another way, But your answer is correct, I didn't use eventinfo_path, (seemed to be having issues with it) Did `eventinfo/#{event.column_a}`, Question is now how do i go about getting html.erb file that matches the name in column_a to show, and not the show.html.erb